# How to use Angular with WordPress as headless server on the same domain?

Tags: angular, wordpress

UPDATED QUESTION:

I know I asked it differently before, but actually that was the question. I just need to put together WordPress and Angular so whenever I go to /wp-admin/ I go to wordpress admin, and whenever I go anywhere else it renders Angular app. The problems with that are:

1. How to remove wordpress templates and always load Angular manifest file? (e.g index.html)
2. How to create manifest that would be `.php` file, but load Angular app?
3. Where to place all Angular files as well as `/dist` folder?

OLD QUESTION:

#### Using .htaccess how to rewrite root to use subfolder, but still allow /wp-admin?

I have set up wordpress, and uploaded in it's root directory my angular app, that has path `/angular/dist/spa`. I need to add rewrite rules to `.htaccess` so any url goes directly to that subfolder, but `/wp-admin/*`.

Can't find fully working solution, it either allows whole app to work or admin panel to work.

Here's my default `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also it'd be helpful if you suggest any other idea how to use angular app inside wordpress (***with no additional plugins***), cuz that's the only way I found, but it feels like there's better ways.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried, and give a proper explanation of what the specific problems were with that? I guess I’d start with a RewritCond that checks the requested path did not start with `/wp-admin/`,followed by a RewriteRule that redirects “everything” to `/angular/dist/spa` then. Guess that alone will probably not be enough though, but then this is rather hard to figure out “in theory”, and without actually sitting in front of the system.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing @CBroe I just went with different approach since my .htaccess approach failed. I just answered this question with the solution I was looking for and finally found. Thanks for your efforts to help me :) HAND

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first you should put your files in WordPress theme. Which has `index.php` file so your angular manifest code (index.html) goes there, but with proper links to assets.

For example here's how it might look like after `ng build --prod`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.b9ab77151b21dce46d94.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime.e227d1a0e31cbccbf8ec.js" defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills.a5e98176150f229fcd04.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts.c5648532e9a6a23906a1.js" defer></script>
    <script src="main.2965e15bb04f185e6e09.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem with the code above is that files have random hashes after the file name and since we're going to put files in a WordPress theme they are going to be placed at `/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/`.

We need to remove hashing in `angular.json`:

```json
...
"outputHashing": "none",
...
```

And add proper paths to assets manually or by adding it to the build command `ng build --prod --deploy-url /wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/`.

So our `index.html` looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/runtime.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/polyfills.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/main.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Perfect! Now we need to move that to the WordPress theme `index.php`:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/runtime.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/polyfills.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/main.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see we replaced some parts with WordPress functions, like `language_attributes`, `bloginfo('charset')`, `body_class`.

Ok. The only problem, is that WordPress is not always loading `index.php`, sometimes it will load `front-page.php`, `404.php` etc. So we need to force the WordPress to always load `index.php`. We can do that by adding this to `function.php` file of the WordPress theme:

```php
add_filter('template_include', function ($template) {
    $template = get_query_template('index');
    return $template;
});
```

Now all we need to do is put `/dist` folder right along with `index.php` file in the theme. And it works!

#### If you want to compile angular on the server

Let's create `angular` folder in our theme and put in there all our angular files. If we run `ng build --prod` it would compile all files and put`/dist` inside the `angular` folder, but we need to put it **outside** so it's accessible with path `/wp-content/themes/%ThemeName%/dist/`. For that we need to add one more setting to `angular.json`:

```json
...
"outputPath": "../dist",
...
```

Brilliant! Our compiled `/dist` folder will be placed outside of current (`angular`) folder and will be accessible for our `index.php` file!

I just described how I got this whole thing to work, hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks for sharing, can't wait to try ;)

Comment: This is a great solution - better than the two subdomains approach imo, because now there's now way for users to get access to the normal Wordpress UI and make edits that they're not supposed to. The one issue I'm running into is directly loading "deep links" (i.e. /pages/my-page), where I'm getting a 301 and a redirect to the original wordpress api structure. I'll post back if I figure something out.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I tried to upload your suggestion by I was getting some `The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.` error in WordPress when I was uploading it. I only have 1 folder (`dist`) and 3 files (`index.php`, `function.php`, `style.css`) inside my theme folder. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress apps should not work along with another frontend framework. Both wordpress and angular should be installed separately on different domains(sub-domains).

What you should be doing then is pulling data from your wordpress installation using [Wordpress REST](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) api and present the posts etc. with Angular or any other framework.

Comment: Hey @rust! That's exactly what my app is doing. It's working with WP REST API. And on my local machine it's working just the way I want. But now it's time to deploy the project, and host it. And I want to host it right along with wordpress that the app is using.

Comment: Yeah, I see your edit. It's not an option for me to use different domains. I know it's possible to use one domain, since I've seen such projects. Just they were on Vue.js and React, and they have a little bit different way of deployment than Angular that I decided to use.

Comment: Is not even a _subdomain_ an option? If you are using WP mainly as an API provider here, that would make the most sense IMHO.

Comment: @AlexChebotarsky "on my local machine it's working" - how does your local environment differ?

Comment: @AlexChebotarsky I'm sure you can create a sub domain and point them to different locations

Comment: @Rust you were right, it's hardly possible to power this whole thing up using .htaccess and placing angular files in a root directory. So I went with different approach and finally got this thing to work on the same domain. I just anwered this question with the solution I was looking for. Thanks for trying to help me :)